# Como o fim do "for" pode ser uma variável definida pelo usuário?

Tags: python, for

Em um [for](/questions/tagged/for) em C, definimos "início, fim e passo de incremento". Sei que em Python não é assim. Vi que é chamado de [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach). Gostaria que o fim do meu [for](/questions/tagged/for) fosse definido pelo usuário. E que, a  cada iteração até o fim do for, fosse requisitado um valor ao usuário e salvo em um vetor.

Tentei:

```
num_tracos = raw_input()

tracos_treino = np.arange(100)

for i in num_tracos:
    print "Digite o traco", i+1, " para o treinamento"
    tracos_treino[i] = raw_input()
```

Também tentei um [while](/questions/tagged/while), mas não deu certo porque nunca acaba (na verdade dá erro quando chega à entrada 101, porque não cabe mais no vetor, mas se não fosse por isso, seria infinito) :

```
num_tracos = raw_input()

 tracos_treino = np.arange(100)

i=0
while i < num_tracos :
    print "Digite o traco", i+1, " para o treinamento"
    tracos_treino[i] = raw_input()
    i = i+1
```

Sempre ouvi que é melhor um [for](/questions/tagged/for) que um [while](/questions/tagged/while), a não ser que você vá iterar initamente (ou seja, nunca). Li isso no "Learn Python The Hard Way".

De toda forma, nenhum dos dois está funcionando como eu gostaria.

Comment: Vejo que está a usar `raw_input`. Que versão do python está a utilizar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qual é a versão do Python que você está utilizando?
Eu vou dar a minha ideia em cima do Python 3.
De fato o for no Python é um pouco diferente do que em C, mas você pode fazer essas tarefas sem problemas, basta entender a estrutura.

Digamos que você quisesse fazer um for para contar de 0 a 9, em C você faria isso da seguinte forma:

```
    for(int c=0; c<10; c++) {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }
```

Em Python isso ficaria um pouco diferente, vide abaixo:

```
    for c in range(0, 10):
        print(c)
```

Repare que no Python, eu utilizo um 'range' de valores a percorrer, neste caso, de 0 a 9, esses valores podem ser substituídos por variáveis.
Você pode também definir o passo da iteração.

```
    for c in range(0, 10, 2):
        print(c)
```

Repare no terceiro parâmetro do range, ele faz com que a contagem aconteça de 2 em 2.
Partindo para a sua pergunta...
No Python temos uma coisa que na minha opinião ajuda bastante, são as listas.

```
    # Definimos uma lista para guardar os valores.
    tracos_treino = []
    # Podemos solicitar ao usuário quantos ítens ele quer inserir na lista.
    tamanho = int(input('Informe a quantidade de ítens desejados:'))
    # Fazemos a iteração.
    # Aqui utilizo a variável 'tamanho' para determinar o fim da contagem.
    for c in range(0, tamanho):
        valor = input('Digite o traco ' + str(c+1) + ' para o treinamento:')
        tracos_treino.append(valor)   # Adiciona ao final da lista.
    # Depois podemos fazer a exibição desses valores.
    for c in range(0, tamanho):
        print(tracos_treino[c])
```

Espero ter ajudado em algo :D

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo! Eu tinha tentado algo como "for c in tamanho:", por isso não funcionou.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, porque o "str" em "valor = input('Digite o traco ' + str(c+1) + ' para o treinamento:')"?

Achei que poderia fazer "valor = input('Digite o traco ', c+1, ' para o treinamento:'). Não?

Comment: Ah, eu uso o Python 2 (2.7.14) e deu certo.

Comment: A variável 'c' é do tipo int, se quisermos concatená-la com uma string precisamos primeiro converter ela para string, por isso o uso do 'str()'. Quando você usa vírgulas para concatenar como "input('Digite o traco ', c+1, ' para o treinamento:')" nesse caso você não está concatenando, mas sim passando três parâmetros para a função input() e o Python vai reclamar, por outro lado isso funciona bem no print().

Comment: É, imaginei. Mesmo no print deu problema, às vezes dizia que não dava pata concatenar str, às vezes não, vai entender.

Answer (score 0):

**Para conseguir implementar aquilo que tem em vista tem de fazer o seguinte:**

- criar uma condição para acabar o ciclo `while`, na definição do mesmo
- criar input na consola para ler uma variável de input
- a partir daí, mapear a variável de input para a condição que dá por encerrado o ciclo `while loop`

**esta definição poderá eventualmente ser algo do género (estrutura de pseudo-código):**

- continuar enquanto variável de input for diferente de 0

**Aí, no final de cada ciclo de iteração deverá colocar o seguinte:**

- deseja continuar (sim - 1, não - 0) - imprimir na consola
- deverá depois ler o input para uma variável que deverá ser a mesma que se encontra no cabeçalho do ciclo quando diz que continua caso seja diferente de 0